# No WiFi on Macbook Retina, also having graphics issues

Tags: 14.04, wireless, resolution, broadcom, macbook

I have a Macbook retina (MacBookPro10,1) and I just installed Ubuntu 15 on an external hard drive and can boot to it with rEFInd.

I'm having two annoying issues though:

1. Ubuntu wont recognize any wifi device, and
2. Anytime I try to change my screen resolution I get a black screen and need to restart.

1) To try and get my WiFi working I followed these steps:

- Download b43_updated.zip onto a USB drive on my Mac, boot into Ubuntu, and place it on the desktop
- `sudo cp b43_updated.zip /lib/firmware/b43` and then `sudo modprobe -rv b43` and `sudo modprobe -v b43`
- restart

After all of that, my WiFi still wont work.
I'd like to follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2/Oneiric#Wireless[1] but the problem is that it assumes I can just plugin in an ethernet cable, which isn't an option for me. So with no internet, I can't `apt-get` the necessary packages. I'm going mental!

2) I'm running a Macbook Retina, so the native resolution is 2880x1800, which makes the screen to way too small, so of course I tried to decrease the resolution. However, anytime I select a lower resolution my screen goes black and there's nothing I can do.

**EDIT**: Here is more information about the hardware from Ubuntu terminal outputs:

`lspci -nn | grep 0280` ->

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n 
[12:4331] (rev 02)
```

`dmesg | grep b43` -->

```
[   22.490777] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4331 WLAN found (core revision 29)
[   22.491165] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 9, Type 7 (HT), Revision 1
[   22.491175] b43-phy0: warning: 5 GHz band is unsupported on this PHY
[   22.982267] b43 bcma0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   22.982270] b43 bcma0:0: Falling back to user helper
... (this repeats 3 more time)
[   more numbers] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode29_mimo.fw" request      
failed (err=-12)
[   more numbers] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode29_mimo.fw"    
request failed (err=-12)
[   more numbers] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver...
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` and also: `dmesg | grep b43`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Hello, just updated the question with that output, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> sudo cp b43_updated.zip /lib/firmware/b43 and then sudo modprobe -rv
>   b43 and sudo modprobe -v b43

I believe you need to unzip the file first. Please try:

```
cd ~/Desktop
unzip b43_updated.zip
```

It extracts into its own folder *b43*. Continue:

```
sudo cp b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

It may take a reboot.

Comment: That was my mistake, I had unzipped it originally, I just forgot to take out the .zip when I typed it up here.

However, after using `sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43` it worked! Thank you very much. You wouldn't happen to know how to fix my graphics issues too would you? :)

Comment: Glad it's working! I am not a graphics guy and I suggest you start a new question.